# Python UTF-8 conversion

Tags: python, string, utf-8

I would like to ask how do the following conversion (source->target) by Python program.

```
>>> source = '\\x{4e8b}\\x{696d}'
>>> print source
\x{4e8b}\x{696d}
>>> print type(source)
<type 'str'>
>>> target = u'\u4e8b\u696d'
>>> print target.encode('utf-8')
事業
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking advantage of Blender's idea, you could use [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callable replacement argument:

```
import re
def touni(match):
    return unichr(int(match.group(1), 16))

source = '\\x{4e8b}\\x{696d}'
print(re.sub(r'\\x\{([\da-f]+)\}', touni, source))
```

yields

```
事業
```

Comment: I suppose you really wouldn't want restrict the matches only to codepoints that have lenght 4 if you are writing a conversion program. Otherwise +1.

Comment: @root: Yes, I suppose that was overly restrictive.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `int` and `unichr` to convert them:

```
>>> int('4e8b', 16)
    20107
>>> unichr(int('4e8b', 16))
    u'\u4e8b'
>>> print unichr(int('4e8b', 16))
事
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'[\W\\x]+')
print ''.join([unichr(int(y, 16)) for y in p.split(source) if y != ''])
事業
```

also stole idea from @Blender...